# ar.js examples not working on Samsung Browser

Tags: android, ar.js, samsung-browser

I know that there are a lot of ar.js examples available, but I did not manage to find one that is really working smooth out of the box on my configuration (Samsung Galaxy S8 + default Samsung Internet browser).

What I did so far:

1. On the Documentation (https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/#getting-started) there is a link called "open this live example" (https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js/aframe/examples/marker-based/basic.html).
   When I open this example the camera zoom is very high so its hard to get the whole marker into the view. In addition to this "zoom-issue" nothing happens when the marker comes into focus. On Chrome the zoom is fine and an object is placed on the marker (not 100% perfect as the object is 90° tilted, but its working somehow).
2. I downloaded the latest sources from https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js and put them on my own server to check the examples. When trying the "basic" example from the three.js/examples folder some files where not found due to wrong paths (path to pattern file + path to camera parameters). After fixing these issues the camera stream is not shown in fullscreen.
3. I tried some other examples from the older repositoryhttps://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/README.md with the same result.

The Samsung Internet Browser (among others) is an absolute must for me, as it is the default browser for a large amount of devices. So hints like "try it on Chrome" would not solve my problem.

All I am searching for is an example that works on the majority of browsers (Safari, Samsung, Chrome, Firefox), shows the camera image in fullscreen mode and tracks a hiro marker.

Comment: Did you make sure you are always using a secure connection (https)? Try building your AR.js using echoAR and compare the differences. I know for a fact it should work with Samsung devices.

Comment: I'm using https connection but I am sure the connection has nothing to do with the wrong zoom as the website is responding and camera starts.
echoAR is a commercial platform. I do not understand how a comparison of ar.js and another commercial tool should help to bugfix this issue.

Comment: Hey, it was just a suggestion you can take it or leave it. Most people find comparing a working example with a non-working example really helpful - just to clarify, I was suggesting to compare with echoAR ar.js solution that uses AR.js exactly the same way you are trying to.
I'm not sure what zoom you are talking about, perhaps you are referring to scale? I would defiantly consider playing around with the scale and making sure the object is not too small or too big.

Comment: I have the same issue with the samsung browser